# Convert horizontal values of a pandas dataframe into vertical values

Tags: python, pandas

I created a pandas dataframe from a dictionary like this:

```
 dictionary={'cat': [B1, B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10], 'Dog': [c1, c2,c3], 'Bird': [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]}
```

`df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary.items(), columns=['ID_1','ID_match'])`

But I get a table looking like this:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

And I would like to be this way:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So far I did this way:

```
df_2_1=df .replace('', np.nan).set_index('ID_1').stack().reset_index(name='ID_match').drop('level_1',1)
```

But I get the second value as list...
Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Solution**:

I just needed to expand the second column:
`df.explode('ID_match')`

Comment: kindly share data, not pics

Comment: I shared data, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work. The first .iloc is taking every other starting with the first column, and the second is taking every other starting with the second column.

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,::2].melt()
df1 = df1['variable']
df2 = df.iloc[:,1::2].melt()
df2 = df2['value']
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':df1, 'col2':df2})
```

Comment: I added a solution, I just needed to expand second column